# Laravel Grouping with eager loading

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, eager-loading

I want to achieve some grouping with eager loading

When I do something like this:

```
$usersWithDepartments = User::with('department')->get();
```

this comes out:

```
[
    {
        "userID": 491,
        "userName": "gigi"
        "deparment": 
        {
            "departmentID": 1,
            "name": "Economy"
        }
    },
    {
        "userID": 444,
        "userName": "gigi2"
        "deparment": 
        {
            "departmentID": 1,
            "name": "Economy"
        }
    }
]
```

But I want to know if it's possible to do something like this:

```
$usersWithDepartments = User::with('department')->groupBy('deparment')->get();
```

in order to get a JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "departmentID": 1,
        "name": "Economy",
        "users":
        [
            {
                "userID": 491,
                "userName": "gigi"            
            },
            {
                "userID": 444,
                "userName": "gigi2"            
            }            
        ]
    }
]
```

I know I could do `Department::with('users')` but I want to keep the same query above in order not to do another query call

if it's not possible. Are any other work arounds?

Comment: Looks like `Department::with('users')` is exactly what you want, I don't understand you wanting to "keep the same query"

Comment: My question is an simplified example of a huge query, in my original query I have almost 4 joins including the one with the eager loading. I don't want to do Department::with('users') because that means running the huge original query again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this

```
$usersWithDepartments = User::with('department')->groupBy('departmentID');
     $usersWithDepartments->toJson();
```

Comment: Actually, I get a 'department' column not found. I think the parameter within groupBy method is a column name not a relationship defined among models. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I just edited the column name 'departmentID' look at my edited answer

Comment: I just did that and still not working. It doesn't do a grouped JSON like in my question.

Comment: try this $usersWithDepartments->toJson();